# How do you consume a json or xml web service in Rails or Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, web-services, json

An external web service is sending json or xml towards my app. What would be the best way to consume this data? Is there a built-in library in Rails or Ruby to do this or do I need to use a gem for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

There's a good explanation of how to use it here:

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/08/scraping-pages-made-easy-with-ruby-and-nokogiri/

Answer (score 3):

For parsing json, you can use rails' method [ActiveSupport::JSON.decode](http://caboo.se/doc/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html) directly in your controller code. For what concerns XML parsing instead, you can choose between rexml (included in the ruby Standard Library), hapricot and libxml-ruby (available via ruby gem).

The choice is ultimately a matter of taste and performance. [This benchmark](http://railstips.org/2008/8/12/parsing-xml-with-ruby) claims that libxml-ruby is the fastest one, though it requires a few other libraries.

Comment: another nice lib for xml is nokogiri, also a rubygem

Answer (score 1):

if it is a web service you query as a source of data, consider making an ActiveResource here is a railscast of the basics

http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics